# Combining couple of commands inside the bash / python script

Tags: python, linux, bash, scripting

I am already doing my job with couple of commands , but I need manual effort and have to observe the job each time. So I want everyhing to be done automatically and I should only be notified if desired result happens. So my scenario is below;

I create results with my script stv.sh

Cmd 1 : `>> timeout 15m  ./stv.sh -parameter1 -parameter2 -output file file1.txt`

than I take the necessary fields from my raw tex file to anoher file

Cmd 2 : `>> sed file1.txt -parameter1 -parameter2 -output file cleanfile1.txt`

than I am adding a test line to my text file

Cmd 3 : `>> cat testline.txt >> cleanfile1.txt`

than I compare my new file with my existing results to find any matching lines

Cmd 4 : `>> comm -12 myexistingresults.txt <(cat cleanfile1.txt | sort | uniq ) > matching.txt`

now, in the matching.txt , at least 1 result will appear in any case because we've included testline.txt with Cmd 2 . But if there is more than one line, the command below needs to run;

Cmd 5 : `>> grep -A 2 $secondlineofmatchingtxt file1.txt > victory.txt`

that means I found a matching line. So, in the matching.txt, if there is more than one line I need to be notified somehow (by sending e-mail etc.) , else if there is only one line in matching.txt , the script needs to start from Cmd 1 again.

How can I establish this goal with a simple bash or python script?

Comment: put all commands in file and you already have bash script. Eventually it may need `shebang` in first line `#!/bin/bash` and you may need to make it executable `chmod +x script` - and then you can run `script` as any other program.

Comment: if you ask how to send email then there are many console program which can send mail - see [16 Command Examples to Send Email From The Linux Command Line](https://blog.edmdesigner.com/send-email-from-linux-command-line/) but not all can work with external Mail Server. `mutt` or `swak` seems interesting - they can even send attachement.

Comment: you can use command `wc -l` (`word count` with option to count only `lines`) to count lines in file - and you can use it with `if/then/fi` in `bash` - ie [6. Conditionals](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-6.html). Shortly: you can find all with Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file to add the interpreter at the top of the file, `#!/bin/bash` and then enter all the commands into one file, allow executable permissions on the file and then run the file.

For the email part you might want to use the exit code of the script `./stv.sh` file. After running this script successfully, find the exit code, and create an `if` statement to test if the exit code matches and if does match, then the email will be sent. Otherwise another way would be to check if the `file1.txt` exists, but this might not be accurate.